# How to show another DataTable with data from the database when the User clicks on a row of one datatable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have two tables with a many-to-many relationship therefore I created another table which has the ID of the two tables.
In my first form I list out the records in the Events table and I want to show to the user the corresponding data from the new table as the user clicks on a record of the visible datatable and my code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CW2
{

    public partial class EditEventForm : Form
    {
        DBAccess dBAccess = new DBAccess();
        DataTable dtUsers = new DataTable();
        public EditEventForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            MenuForm form = new MenuForm();
            form.Show();
        }

        private void EditEventForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView2.Hide();
            String query = "Select * from Event";
            dBAccess.readDatathroughAdapter(query, dtUsers);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtUsers;
            dBAccess.closeConn();
        }

        private void buttontransfertoDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String query = "Select * from Event";
            int changes = dBAccess.executeDataAdapter(dtUsers, query);
            MessageBox.Show("You made " + changes + " changes");

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dataGridView2.Show();
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            int eventID = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());

            String query = ("Select * from Event_Contacts where EventID=@eventID");
            dBAccess.executeDataAdapter(dt,query);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
            dBAccess.closeConn();
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error when i execute it as follows:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@eventID".'

Please assist me in solving this!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `DBAccess()` is but you need to specify what your parameter @eventID is, if you're using a `DataAdapter` this is typically done like,

```
DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventID", yourEventIDValue);
```

Comment: I added String query = "Select * from Event_Contacts where EventID=" + eventID.ToString(); But it now displays an empty grid view

Comment: Errors do not display anymore, Its just a blank grid view

Comment: @HimashiWeerasinghe does your query return any results?

Answer (score 0):

Cahnge;

```
String query = "Select * from Event_Contacts where EventID=" + eventID.ToString();
```